# Which mosfet to use?

Tags: powermosfet

I’m working on a project which calls for a (5 volt 100 mA output) ir break beam activating a solenoid valve when the beam gets interrupted. It’s a 2 amp 12 volt solenoid.
What would be a suitable mosfet in order to make this work?

Any help would be very much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What's the function of the 10K resistor?  Does the sensor have a nice sharp detection threshold, or does it turn on or off softly?  D2, as drawn, does nothing unless it's a zener diode.

Comment: D2 should be across solenoid with reverse polarity to what is shown. | Sensor symbol could be better chosen - and may be just-wrong based on text. ie if it is a 2 lead LDR that is low resistance when illuminated it should be shown as eg a resistor between ground asnd gate with an appropriate name (eg LDR1, ...). Showing actual sensor name and a link to a data sheet helps heaps. | Almost any N channel MOSFET with Vgsth well below 5V will work.

Answer (score 1):

Please give D1 a 220ohm resistor, and put Diode D2 between the +12V and the drain of the transistor so that it is paralel to the solenoid. The pin of D2 that is connected to the ground must be connected to the drain, and the pin that was connected to the drain must be connected to the +12V.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a diode then D2 should be across solenoid with reverse polarity to what is shown.

If it is a zener diode, location as shown is OK but symbol should show a zener.

The sensor symbol could be better chosen so that it reflects its function and nature.
Does it REALLY have 3 pins? If so, what do they do?
What is its manufacturer-name?

Sensor as shown **may** be "just-wrong" -  based on your text.
ie if it is a 2 lead LDR that is low resistance when illuminated it should be shown as eg a resistor between ground and gate with an appropriate name (eg LDR1, ...).
Showing the actual sensor name and a link to a data sheet helps heaps.

---

Almost any N channel MOSFET with Vgsth well below 5V, 5A say rated I continuous, 20V say Vd,  will work.

I set up a sample search using Digikey's selection tool but it now seems to not allow saving the final search (as it used to :-(.).

Use [**this starting point**](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278) and subset as required. I got about 1600 potentially suitable parts. (Nchannel, > 5A, > 20V, Igsth <= 3V, in stock, available in 1 quantity, ...)

In the absence of a savable URL see this image.
Click image to enlarge. 
Click resultant image to enlarge further.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The kickback diode can be a regular diode, limiting the reverse pulse to 0.7V, or a Schottky diode, typically having a Vf of 200-300mV, or a Zener diode, with a specific reverse breakdown voltage.  The diode is essential.  It needs to have a voltage max limit that is greater than the kickback voltage.  A 2A 12V solenoid is going to have a pretty hefty kickback (V ~= -dB/dT, where dB is massive, dT is very small and ~= means "is proportional to").  Many MOSFETs have the kickback diode built in; just check the datasheet for presence and ratings.

Answer (score 0):

An IRF510 would do the job nicely.

Answer (score -1):

I like AOD508, AOD514 from Digikey.com for surface mount parts.
Easy to drive full on with 4.5V source, and very low Rds.

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-fets-mosfets-single/278?k=aod5

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is getting me somewhere